# User control fails to start due to null fields

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

My User control fails to start due to null fields and Im getting really annoyed, I have the code under:

```
       public MyControl()
       {
        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
         base.OnInitialized(e);
         string userinputMainWindow = (string)App.Current.Properties["TextBoxString"];
         Foreach
         {
            TextBlock textBlock2 = new TextBlock();
            textBlock2.Text = String.Format(userinputMainWindow); // null
            textBlock2.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
```

But I dont think this is what I need, how can I stop the code from initializing on startup and  only initializaing when I call the code?

For instance on my main window I call the usercontrol like this:

```
    private Dictionary<string, UserControl> _userControls = new Dictionary<string, UserControl>();
    public Dictionary<string, UserControl> GetUserControls()
    {
        return _userControls;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> userControlKeys = new List<string>();
        userControlKeys.Add("MyControl");
        Type type = this.GetType();
        Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;
        foreach (string userControlKey in userControlKeys)
        {
            string userControlFullName = String.Format("{0}.UserControls.{1}", type.Namespace, userControlKey);
            UserControl userControl = (UserControl)assembly.CreateInstance(userControlFullName);
            _userControls.Add(userControlKey, userControl);
        }

    }
    private void btnGeneral_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        App.Current.Properties["TextBoxString"] = textBox1.Text;

        PanelMainContent.Children.Clear();
        Button button = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
        Type type = this.GetType();
        Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;

        PanelMainContent.Children.Add(_userControls[button.Tag.ToString()]);
    }
```

Is there a way to stop the user control initializing and only when I click the `btnGeneral_Click`?

Comment: When are you creating an instance of `_userControls`?  Can you do that inside of `btnGeneral_Click` instead?

Comment: I already do see update, the problem is on startup tho... I cant start because some of the usercontrol fields are null because it uses the main window to pass information when a user types information.

Comment: Can you post the code from your UserControl? What fields are null? When are you trying to set them?

Comment: @roomaroo see update, just passing a string from main window to usercontrol, but on startup `userinputMainWindow` is null

Comment: I just need to find a way to stop the usercontrol initializing so that there is an input in the textbox and it will actualy pass something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, this sort of thing would normally be done through data binding, but you can get this working quickly by just setting a property on your usercontrol before you add it to the panel.

Add a property to your user control:

```
public string TextBlockString
{
    get
    {
        return this.textBlock2.Text;
    }

    set
    {
        this.textBlock2.Text = value;
    }
}
```

And then in `btnGeneral_Click`:

```
private void btnGeneral_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    App.Current.Properties["TextBoxString"] = textBox1.Text;

    PanelMainContent.Children.Clear();
    Button button = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
    Type type = this.GetType();
    Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;

    MyControl myControl = _userControls[button.Tag.ToString()];
    myControl.TextBlockString = textBox1.Text;

    PanelMainContent.Children.Add(myControl);
}
```